# How would I create a PHP script that completes and submits forms on third party websites

Tags: php

I'm building a web application that will automatically complete user forms online for many different websites.  My guess is I will have to open windows through the system search for the form fields and post address, then auto post, but I have no idea where to start.

Sorry for this extremely vague (potentially naive) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would take a look at using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) . there's plenty of [examples of submitting forms using it](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

Comment: and what if form has something simple as image protection?

Comment: I think, I'll create a script to automatically send these instances to crowdflower or mechanical turk, but I think cURL or phpQuery will satisfy most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remoting a browser or whatever you had in mind, you want to check out [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

It allows to parse websites, extract forms, and issue requests (pseudo AJAX, needs some configuration).